# Convert Whole Digit to Date Format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to convert the Day column to a standard date format. 1 for Nov 1 (current month), 2 for Nov 2, and so on. Would be nice if the formula will display the current month. The format for the Day column is in general.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, use `=A2+43039` and format cells as Custom: `d-mmm`

Also possible to use `=A2+"10/31/2017"` to make it clearer what you're doing in the formula.

However, if you want it to update with whatever the current month and year is, Ralph's answer is probably best.

Comment: This is the only solution offered that will not change the values if you open last month's workbook/worksheet.

Comment: I agree with Jeeped. If the month changes, I just change the date to retain the previous date values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the following formula into cell `B2` (if that's your `Date` column and `Day` is in the `A` column) and then copy it down:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),A2)
```

Comment: You can get the same result using `=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+A2`